# Third party private chat between online users .NET Application

Tags: asp.net, chat

Does anyone know of third party software that can be used in a .Net application similar to what facebook chat does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up [this](http://www.aspnetajaxchat.com/).  Conversely, maybe you're looking for something more like [one](http://cutesoft.net/web-messenger/) [of](http://www.sitescripts.com/ASP.NET/Chat_and_Instant_Messaging/) [these](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=54).

We'll gladly help you with any programming related issues when you get into developing and integrating something for your site.  But it sounds like you're still at the Googling-for-ideas phase.

Comment: Yes.  I am googling for ideas.  I found this.  Is anyone using it?  http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/

Comment: I am looking for a chat application that can be embedded on the page.  Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: obautista i am also dealing with same problem did u find any solution